# How to authenticate user in Azure using the REST API?

Tags: rest, azure, authentication

I have a user account in Microsoft Azure Active Directory. I am able to provision VMs and other resources in the web portal. I would like to replicate this functionality over a REST API.

I am reading the [Azure AD REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/index) and the first step is to register a client application with Azure AD. However I wish to simply authenticate with my user account credentials rather than through a client application. Is this possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? Do you want to simply no longer use the Portal and just do this at a command-line, or are you looking to build your own mini management portal or client?

Comment: I want to automate some of the operations and use the REST API as an interface. For now I have registered a client application and I am using non-interactive authentication documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service). The request returns an access token that I can use to make other requests.

Comment: Are you saying you want to call the Azure management services with an AD credential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am reading the Azure AD REST API documentation and the first step is to register a client application with Azure AD. However I wish to simply authenticate with my user account credentials rather than through a client application. Is this possible?

As far as I know, if we want to access or modify resources using **REST API protected by Azure AD** in our application, we must set up an Active Directory application and assign the required permissions to it. We need to retrieve access token before accessing resource, and then we make the REST API calls take the access token to access or modify resource. And as you have done, it enables us to retrieve access token via non-interactive request with client credentials.

Comment: In the non-interactive authentication token request, there is a parameter named "resource". The docs says that it should be the App ID URI of the receiving web service. However, if I use the token obtained in a different REST call, I get the following message:
`InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience","message":"The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource '<MyAppID_URI>'. It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.azure.com/'.`
  
What does this mean?